# JSON blank and null value comes as true in JSON Object

Tags: java, json

I am getting JSON value as true if I add blank or null values in JSON Object.

```
$scope.getUserData = function (){   
    $.ajax({
          url: "/test.com/abc.jsp",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            action : "getUserData",
            id : Id,
            logView:"true",
        },
          async:false,
          success: function(data){
            // data is json array and userData is json object           
            $scope.userData = JSON.parse(data.userData);
            $scope.userData.uname // comes as true but from server it is set as blank
          });
    });
}
```

In server side java code I get values from data as blank/null but in JSON object comes as true for blank/null. It works in my local but in server environment it comes as true for blank/null.